# не работает success в jquery

Tags: javascript, php

В консоли ошибку не выводит, код срабатывает до success

```
$('.register-btn').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    $(`input`).removeClass('error');
  
    let login = $('input[name="login_input"]').val(),
        password = $('input[name="password_input"]').val(),
        first_name = $('input[name="first_name_input"]').val(),
        name = $('input[name="name_input"]').val(),
        last_name = $('input[name="last_name_input"]').val(),
        phone = $('input[name="phone_input"]').val(),
        date = $('input[name="date_input"]').val(),
        radio = $('input[name="radio"]').val(),
        password_confirm = $('input[name="password_confirm_input"]').val();
  
    let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('login_input', login);
        formData.append('password_input', password);
        formData.append('password_confirm_input', password_confirm);
        formData.append('first_name_input', first_name);
        formData.append('name_input', name);
        formData.append('last_name_input', last_name);
        formData.append('phone_input', phone);
        formData.append('date_input', date);
        formData.append('radio', radio);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'vendor/singup.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      data: formData,
      success (data) {
        console.log("+");
        if (data.status) {
          document.location.href = './login.php';
        } else {
          if (data.type === 1) {
            data.fields.forEach(function (field) {
              $(`input[name="${field}"]`).addClass('error');
            });
          }
          $('.msg').removeClass('none').text(data.message);
        }
      }
    }); 
});
```

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$login_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['login_input']);
$password_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_input']);
$password_confirm_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password_confirm_input']);
$last_name_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['last_name_input']);
$name_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name_input']);
$first_name_input = htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name_input']);
$phone_input = $_POST['phone_input'];
$date_input = $_POST['date_input'];
$radio = $_POST['radio'];

$check_login = $connection->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `login` = "$login_input"')->fetchColumn();
var_dump($check_login);
if ($check_login > 0) {
    $respone = [
        "status" => false,
        "type" => 1,
        "message" => "Такой логин уже существует!",
        "fields" => ['login']
    ];

    echo json_encode($respone);
    die();
}

$error_fields = [];

if ($login_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'login_input';
}

if ($password_input === '') { 
    $error_fields[] = 'password_input';
}

if ($password_confirm_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'password_confirm_input';
}

if ($last_name_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'last_name_input';
}

if ($name_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'name_input';
}

if ($first_name_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'first_name_input';
}

if ($phone_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'phone_input';
}

if ($date_input === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'date_input';
}

if ($radio === '') {
    $error_fields[] = 'radio';
}

if (!empty($error_fields)) {
    $response = [
        "status" => false,
        "type" => 1,
        "message" => "Проверьте правильность полей!",
        "fields" => $error_fields
    ];

    echo json_encode($response);

    die();
}

if (strlen($password_input) < 8 ) {
    $response = [
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Пароль слишком маленький!",
    ];
    
    echo json_encode($response);

    die();
}

if ($password_input === $password_confirm_input) {

    $password = md5($password);

    $safe = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`, `password`,`first_name`,`name`,`last_name`,`phone`,`date_of_birth`,`gender`) VALUES (:login, :password, :first_name, :name, :last_name, :phone, :date_of_birth, :gender)");
    $arr = ['login'=>$login_input, 'password'=>$password_input, 'first_name'=>$first_name_input, 'name'=>$name_input, 'last_name'=>$last_name_input, 'phone'=>$phone_input, 'date_of_birth'=>$date_input, 'gender'=>$radio];
    $safe->execute($arr);
    $response = [
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Регистрация прошла успешно!",
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response = [
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Пароли не совпадают!",
    ];
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Вводимые данные

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что на сервере написано?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как это посмотреть?)

Comment: в файле `vendor/singup.php`. Кстати, возможно должно быть `url: '/vendor/singup.php',`. Но это не точно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вам именно код нужен или что выводит этот файл?

Comment: код)) может там что-то не то написано...... плюс попробуйте поставить `/` перед `vendor`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский добавил код в вопрос

Comment: @НикитаБаканин, у Вас в php коде есть строка с ```var_dump```.  Ну а после нее вы пытаетесь отправить json.  Ну и следовательно возвращается невалидный json. Как минимум ```data.type``` уже вызовет ошибку

Comment: @Crasher Все сработало, весь день искал ошибку
Спасибо что помогли